# How to separate User Based LogIn and Admin Based Login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc4. I need a help,, When i logging as a admin It should go the admin page, and also when i am logging as a user it should go to the user page,, How to do it..Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of login check user status and store it in session, and after that check if status is admin redirect to admin page otherwise user page. Like that:

```
Session["User"]="admin";
```

Comment: Session["User"]="admin";
if(Session["User"].tostring=="admin")
{
return RedirectToAction("adminpage", "Home");
}
else
{
return RedirectToAction("userpage", "Home");
}

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience, This line showing error.Please help me to resolve this problem. if (Session["User"].ToString == "admin")       Error message:operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'

Comment: use it's 
string status = Session["User"].ToString();
            if (status == "admin");